# compute the spectrum of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $C_{0}(\mathbb R)$ be the space of complex continuous valued functions on $\mathbb R$ which vanish at $\infty$ equipped with the sup-norm. Let $S:C_{0}(\mathbb R) \to C_{0}(\mathbb R)$ given by $(Sf)(t)=f(t+s)$ for a fixed $s\in \mathbb R$. 
 Prove that the spectrum of $\sigma(S)$ is given by the set $\sigma(S)=\{z\in \mathbb C ; ||z||=1\}$.

I proved that if $|\lambda|\ne 1$ then $\lambda \in p(T)$. I want to prove that if $|\lambda|=1$ then $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$
Since if $|\lambda|=1$ I proved that $\lambda I-T$ it's injective. It remains to prove that $\lambda I-T$ it's not surjective.

Thanks for the tips! But it remains to prove that if $||z||=1$ then $z\in \sigma(T)$. And I don't know how

Comment: N.B. Your notation is rather nonstandard, at least in operator algebras and noncommutative geometry: the standard notation there is $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ for the space you denote by $C_\infty(\mathbb{R})$, which is rather too close for comfort to $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, which denotes instead the algebra of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić I changed the notation. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explicitly compute the inverse of $\lambda I - T$ for $|\lambda|<1$? Remember, $T^{-1}$ is trivially computable. And take inspiration from the formula $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x+x^2+\ldots$ if $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be a complete answer, but is just to indicate an idea of why the statement might be true:

The space $\mathcal C_0$ is dense in $L^2$, and so the spectrum of $S$ on $\mathcal C_0$ should be closely related to its spectrum as an operator on $L^2$.

On the other hand, $L^2$ is morally the direct sum of the the various one-dimensional spaces spanned by the functions $e^{ixy}$; more precisely, the theory
of the Fourier transform exhibits $L^2$ as the *direct integral* of these lines.

On the the line spanned by $e^{ixy}$, the operator $S$ acts as multiplictation by $e^{isy}$.  As $y$ varies over all elements of $\mathbb R$, the eigenvalues
$e^{isy}$ vary over all elements of absolute value $1$ in $\mathbb C$.  Thus,
at least morally, the spectrum of $S$ on $L^2$ is equal to the set of elements of $\mathbb C$ of absolute value $1$, and so (again, at least morally), the
same should be true of $S$ acting on $C_0$.

Comment: And what about if $|\lambda|=1$?

Comment: Dear Madara, I've given you a conceptual indication of why the spectrum should be exactly the set $|\lambda| = 1$.  Have you tried yourself to make it into a proof?  Regards,

Comment: I would like to, but I don't understand at all, what do you mean by the line spanned by $e^{ixy}$ what line. Sorry for being so stupid ._.

Comment: @Madara: Dear Madara, I mean that the theory of Fourier transforms can be thought of intuitively as saying that $L^2 = \bigoplus_{y \in \mathbb R} \mathbb C \cdot e^{ixy}.$ This is not actually true, because the function $e^{ixy}$ is not in $L^2$; but it gives a way to try to think about operator theory on $L^2$, or related spaces like $C_0$.  Regards,

Answer (score 2):

If $0\le|\lambda|<1$, you can explicitly compute
$$
(\lambda I - T) ^{-1} = -\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{i}T^{-i-1}.
$$
You can verify this is, indeed, an inverse and it's continuous.

Comment: Use the same idea when $|\lambda|<1$. Write $\lambda I - T = (\lambda T^{-1} - I)T$, then invert this expression.

Comment: For anyone confused by my above comment: it was written in responses to another comment that's since been deleted. Although the formula I wrote for the inverse does not work for $|\lambda|>1$, the same basic trick works. In that  case, just write $(\lambda I - T)^{-1} = \lambda^{-1} (I - \lambda^{-1} T)^{-1}$ and use the usual expansion $(I-A)^{-1} = \sum_{i\ge 0} A^i$, which works whenever $||A||<1$.